# Fullscreen tearing in Firefox Flash video with AMD Catalyst drivers

Tags: firefox, flash, catalyst, mint, tearing

Since upgrading to Linux Mint 17, every time I put a flash video into fullscreen it starts tearing up, then freezes after a couple seconds. This only happens when I have the proprietary AMD drivers installed. I am currently running fglrx-updates from the driver manager, and have also tested this with fglrx and also the drivers from the AMD homepage.

I have also manually installed flash player from Adobe, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: What graphics card are you using? Try upgrading to the latest AMD Catalyst drivers, and if it still tears, file a bug with AMD.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I updated the kernel to 3.13.0-27.
So I booted back into old 3.13.0-24 and removed the -27 in the update manager > view > Linux Kernels. 
No tearing/freezing full screen flash videos with proprietary AMD drivers in Firefox again.
Hope it works for U too.